# Are Diffie-Hellman and ECC public key / asymmetric cryptographies?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman

I have a doubt.

In RSA we generate a public key `(e,n)` and a private key `(d,n)`. and the these keypairs are actually used to encrypt (by public-key) and decrypt (by private-key) the actual data during communication.

`m^(e*d) = m (mod n)` because `m^(k*phi(n)+1) = m (mod n)`

But Diffie-Hellman and ECC algorithms are just used to generate a common secrete key (K) between two parties, which is then used for symmetric encryption.

So, Diffie-Hellman and ECC are just Key Generation/Exchange algorithms, and do not actually use asymmetric encryption-decryption, whereas RSA is asymmetric cryptography because it do use two different keys for encryption decryption.

So why are Diffie-Hellman and ECC counted as Public/Private Key Cryptographies?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: They are called public key/private keys or asymmetric crypto for the simple reason that the public key of the keypair is known to everyone and the private key must be known only to its owner. Hence the asymmetry. Symmetric cryptography keys are such that the same (symmetric) key must be known by both communicants. Hybrid cryptography uses the strengths of both asymmetric and symmetric cryptography.

Comment: ECC Public Key Encryption
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9987/elgamal-with-elliptic-curves
https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866109-5/